# How do you properly loop through a file for tasks within a block in Ansible?

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, foreach, ansible

This has been a challenge and I am stuck on what else to try. Basically, I have a text file that has an unknown amount of lines. I wish to read through each line and set facts for each line that is then used as variables for a win_domain_user module.

If there is only one line in the text file, then I can accomplish my task with no issues or errors. But, if there is more than one line, I do not know how to start the process again with the next line.

For example:

```
- name: "Pre-task AD | Get user account info"
  win_shell: |
    Get-Content C:\AD\user_info.txt
  register: 'read_output'
```

The line of text in the user_info.txt file looks like this:

```
first-John;last-Doe;display_name-Doe, John (US);title-Engineer;employee_type-Employee;user-john.doe;email-john.doe@company.com;customer-Some_Business;dept_groups-Test_Group
```

Example of two lines:

```
first-John;last-Doe;display_name-Doe, John (US);title-Engineer;employee_type-Employee;user-john.doe;email-john.doe@company.com;customer-Some_Business;dept_groups-Test_Group
first-Jane;last-Doe;display_name-Doe, Jane (US);title-Engineer II;employee_type-Employee;user-jane.doe;email-jane.doe@company.com;customer-Some_Business;dept_groups-Test_Group
```

The set facts looks like:

```
- set_fact:
    first: "{{ read_output.stdout | regex_search(...) }}"
    last: "{{ read_output.stdout | regex_search(...) }}"
    user: "{{ read_output.stdout | regex_search(...) }}"
    email: "{{ read_output.stdout | regex_search(...) }}"
    customer: "{{ read_output.stdout | regex_search(...) }}"
    title: "{{ read_output.stdout  regex_search(...) }}"
    display_name: "{{ read_output.stdout  regex_search(...) }}"
    employee_type: "{{ read_output.stdout |  regex_search(...) }}"
    dept_groups: "{{ read_output.stdout |  regex_search(...) }}"
```

The winrm Active Directory related module looks like:

```
- name: "Active Directory | Add domain user account to domain controller"
  win_domain_user:
    firstname: "{{ first }}"
    surname: "{{ last }}"
    name: "{{ first }}{{ space }}{{ last }}"
    description: "{{ title }}"
    password: "{{ password_var_here}}"
    upn: "{{ user }}{{ domain_fqdn_var_here }}"
    email: "{{ email }}"
    state: 'present'
    path: "{{ ou_path_here }}"
    groups: "Domain Users, {{ dept_groups }}"
    attributes:
      displayName: "{{ first }}{{ space }}{{ last }}"
    domain_username: "{{ domainusername_var_here }}"
    domain_password: "{{ domainpassword_var_here }}"
    domain_server: "{{ dc_var_here }}"
  register: 'add_ad_user'
```

I tried using a win_shell ForEach (PowerShell) loop to action the lines in C:\AD\user_info.txt but I was not able to figure out how to use set_facts within the ForEach loop and use the win_domain_user module within it. So, instead, I looked into using with_items which from what I understand is now loop. From the info above, I was going to create 2 yml files, one that has the 'Get-Content C:\AD\user_info.txt' / register and then use the include_tasks yml with block for the tasks to run against the data from the Get-Content.

The tricky part is that I do not know how many lines are going to be in that user_info.txt file. Am I on the right track as far as using two files for this or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Rather than trying to get Ansible to parse an unfamiliar file format, use `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, etc., to get the file into a useful format that Ansible can just read.

Comment: The file is coming from a Windows system using a Windows winrm module. Parsing the text is no problem. The issue is I would like to be able to read the lines from the file to loop over several tasks in a block. The is basically for automating adding new users to Active Directory. When it is done with the win_domain_user task, I would like it to go back up top to the text file and process the second line in the same manner.

Comment: Like I said, it will be easier to read in a file formatted for Ansible, such as JSON, so you get it into a dictionary and loop over the dictionary.

Comment: So the *n* number of lines of your command's output will be in the registered variable's `stdout_lines`.

Comment: This aside, how are you going to associate the `password` parameter for the users listed in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line from the file will be in the registered variable `read_output.stdout_lines`. We can loop with this variable and split the line using semi-colon (`;`) to get the individual attributes of the user.

If we take only the first line, the example below with return `John`:

```
"{{ read_output.stdout_lines[0].split(';')[0].split('-')[1] }}"
```

Similarly a `debug` task:

```
- name: "Pre-task AD | Get user account info"
  win_shell: |
    Get-Content C:\AD\user_info.txt
  register: read_output

- name: Show user details after splitting
  debug:
    msg:
      - "First: {{ first }}"
      - "Last: {{ last }}"
      - "Display name: {{ display_name }}"
  vars:
    first: "{{ item.split(';')[0].split('-')[1] }}"
    last: "{{ item.split(';')[1].split('-')[1] }}"
    display_name: "{{ item.split(';')[2].split('-')[1] }}"
  loop: "{{ read_output.stdout_lines }}"
```

will produce:

```
    "msg": [
        "First: John",
        "Last: Doe",
        "Display name: Doe, John (US)"
    ]
```

Continuing with this theme, we can have the `win_domain_user` task like (not tested):

```
- name: "Active Directory | Add domain user account to domain controller"
  win_domain_user:
    firstname: "{{ first }}"
    surname: "{{ last }}"
    name: "{{ first }} {{ last }}"
    description: "{{ title }}"
    password: "{{ password_var_here }}"
    upn: "{{ user }}{{ domain_fqdn_var_here }}"
    email: "{{ email }}"
    state: 'present'
    path: "{{ ou_path_here }}"
    groups: "Domain Users, {{ dept_groups }}"
    attributes:
      displayName: "{{ first }} {{ last }}"
    domain_username: "{{ domainusername_var_here }}"
    domain_password: "{{ domainpassword_var_here }}"
    domain_server: "{{ dc_var_here }}"
  vars:
    first: "{{ item.split(';')[0].split('-')[1] }}"
    last: "{{ item.split(';')[1].split('-')[1] }}"
    display_name: "{{ item.split(';')[2].split('-')[1] }}"
    name: "{{ first }} {{ last }}"
    title: "{{ item.split(';')[3].split('-')[1] }}"
    email: "{{ item.split(';')[6].split('-')[1] }}"
    user: "{{ item.split(';')[5].split('-')[1] }}"
    dept_groups: "{{ item.split(';')[8].split('-')[1] }}"
  loop: "{{ read_output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: That's a lot of splitting to write and it will very easily break if any of the fields changes position in the source. Meanwhile, it works ;)

Comment: Agreed. There is already a lot of indication that the source file format is brittle, so I didn't want to repeat it in my answer. And I tried to work with what we have.

Comment: Well there is actually a way to combine my first idea with yours to have something lighter that will adapt to the actual format and get the field names dynamically. Updating my answer.

Comment: I can't up-vote twice for kudo's but thanks for opening my eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, the real good solution would be to change your file format at source to something that is easy to parse. Being in ansible the best format would indeed be yaml/json. But any other standard would make this much easier (xml, csv...).

*Note: I know your current data is actually csv with semicolon delimiters. But it doesn't have a header and values contain the field name that must be extracted on each line*

As an other remark: registering the output of a cat command (e.g. `Get-Content`) from a `(win-)shell` to get a file content is a bad practice. This is precisely why the [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) and [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) modules exist.

The below is just a workaround to get a `dict` out of your custom and not really ideal format. It will break as soon as a value does not strictly respect the current inferred schema (i.e. contains a dash, a semicolon, a new line...) and will probably become a real nightmare to maintain every time you encounter an exception. But at least it does what you expect from your example and you can build upon that to adapt it to your exact needs.

**Edit**: my original solution was using a regex (see [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68879889/revisions) if you want to look at it). But @seshadri_c opened my eyes on a much simpler solution that leads to the same result using only `split`. I borrowed the idea while keeping the key/value mapping dynamic.

Given the following `files/user_data.txt`

```
first-John;last-Doe;display_name-Doe, John (US);title-Engineer;employee_type-Employee;user-john.doe;email-john.doe@company.com;customer-Some_Business;dept_groups-Test_Group
first-Jane;last-Doe;display_name-Doe, Jane (US);title-Engineer II;employee_type-Employee;user-jane.doe;email-jane.doe@company.com;customer-Some_Business;dept_groups-Test_Group
```

The `loop_bad_file.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Loop on a poorly formated file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # File name on the remote (here relative to the current dir for the example....)
    bad_file_name: files/user_data.txt

    # list of user dicts we get by:
    #
    # 1. spliting each line from the original file (`select` removes the last trainling blank line)
    # So we get ['line1....', 'line2....']
    #
    # 2. split each line on semicolons so we get:
    # [['key1-value1', 'key2-value2', ....], ['key1-value1', 'key2-value2', ....], ...]
    #
    # 3. split each field-value on a dash so we get:
    # [[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ..., [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ...], ...]
    #
    # 4. Turn this back into a list of dicts using the key/values pairs in each element
    user_list: "{{
        (bad_file.content | b64decode).split('\n') | select
        | map('split', ';')
        | map('map', 'split', '-')
        | map('items2dict', key_name=0, value_name=1)
    }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Get file content from remote
      slurp:
        src: "{{ bad_file_name }}"
      register: bad_file

    - name: Show the result using the transformed list of dicts
      vars:
        debug_msg: |-
          This is entry for {{ item.display_name }}
          first: {{ item.first }}
          last: {{ item.last }}
          title: {{ item.title }}
          employee type: {{ item.employee_type }}
          email: {{ item.email }}
          customer: {{ item.customer }}
          department group: {{ item.dept_groups }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ debug_msg.split('\n') }}"
      loop: "{{ user_list }}"
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook loop_bad_file.yml 

PLAY [Loop on a poorly formated file] *********************************************************************

TASK [Get file content from remote] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the result using the transformed list of dicts] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe', 'display_name': 'Doe, John (US)', 'title': 'Engineer', 'employee_type': 'Employee', 'user': 'john.doe', 'email': 'john.doe@company.com', 'customer': 'Some_Business', 'dept_groups': 'Test_Group'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "This is entry for Doe, John (US)",
        "first: John",
        "last: Doe",
        "title: Engineer",
        "employee type: Employee",
        "email: john.doe@company.com",
        "customer: Some_Business",
        "department group: Test_Group"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'first': 'Jane', 'last': 'Doe', 'display_name': 'Doe, Jane (US)', 'title': 'Engineer II', 'employee_type': 'Employee', 'user': 'jane.doe', 'email': 'jane.doe@company.com', 'customer': 'Some_Business', 'dept_groups': 'Test_Group'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "This is entry for Doe, Jane (US)",
        "first: Jane",
        "last: Doe",
        "title: Engineer II",
        "employee type: Employee",
        "email: jane.doe@company.com",
        "customer: Some_Business",
        "department group: Test_Group"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This code is concise and can handle (dynamic) changes in position of the respective fields  (`key-value`) on a line!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use `csvfile` lookup plugin [1] to load data from csv file as a variable or iterable object.

[1] https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/csvfile_lookup.html